# Memory debugging tools for Android NDK C++ code

Tags: c++, android-ndk, valgrind

Does anyone know of memory debugging tools (like Valgrind) for native C++ code under Android NDK?

Comment: The ARM version of valgrind has been "coming soon" for years.  If you setprop libc.debug.malloc to 10 and stop/start you will get some additional checks, but I haven't found them to be all that helpful.

Comment: Seperate your jni (glue code between java and native impl.) and native implementaion. Using x86 debug tool handle native implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have a project that uses quite a bit of native code. As hinted in one of the comments for the question, the best approach is to test that code on another environment.

We have a separate project that builds in Linux and calls the C/C++ functions we use in our Android code. Once you are at that point, all the nice tools you are used to (gdb, Valgrind, etc.) are available to you.

A lot more productive than doing the same thing on the phone (assuming you could even find a good tool).

The tricky part is to have a good test harness, but that should be a given to any project that started off on the right path... ;)