# Memory leaks & Memory Corruptions in Android Native Code

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind, memory-corruption

Is anybody used Valgrind for Android Native Code ?

Is there any way to find out Memory leak and Memory Corruption in Native Code of Android ?

Regards
Rke

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446093/memory-debugging-tools-for-android-ndk-c-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094242/how-to-find-memory-leaks-from-native-code-in-android

Comment: Thanks hanung, but that link didn't help me...........Can anybody have some more idea about this :-(